# Committed to GitHub and an RPC error came up

Tags: git, github, git-push

I made a new GitHub repository, and made a website and tried to commit the code to the repo - but then this error popped up after I did the following steps:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/[MyUsername]/[MyRepo].git
git push -u origin master
```

And after I did the last step, this error came up:

```
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (94/94), 30.29 MiB | 477.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 94 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I've committed to GitHub and everything worked fine before...only recently it gave me this error? I was trying to search the problem up but I didn't get any results...

I'm using Windows 10 with VS Code - if you need anymore info, please feel free to ask. I would really appreciate it if someone would be able to give me some advice! Thank you!

Comment: This is some kind of failure during the https connection-and-transfer process. Your Git software sent everything it wanted to send, and was waiting for an acknowledgement (or error) from GitHub, but then the connection died before it got either an all-OK or error response. You can retry in case it was just a temporary network glitch, or you can try using ssh instead of https.

Comment: Are you using an antivirus or firewall other than the Windows default, or any sort of proxy?  Those can often cause these problems.

Comment: @bk2204 hmm, I don't think so...I think only the Windows default one?

Comment: @torek thank you, I will try that - I do have problems with my internet...do you think that might be the issue?

Comment: @WaffleBoots: definitely *could* be. Another problem that some have seen occurs when a receiving Git wants to run a lot of checking software before accepting some commit(s). If this takes *too* long, your computer might decide that their computer has gone off line, just because it has not heard anything back in a while. It's like when you're on hold on the phone and nobody has checked in with you for three hours, are they still there?

Comment: @torek that's interesting...my internet always drops off and on often, so I will try using the hotspot. Is there a solution to fix that problem you just described, however?

Comment: With ssh, you can set / adjust keepalives. Not sure if there's anything you can do with https/libcurl.

Answer (score 2):

To my mind, in this project hasn't it branch. Check it correct project

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking for an answer and not trying to push to the master branch.

Check the branch name. For me, it was a mistake with uppercase/lowercase letters. Try "git branch" before pushing to make sure you have the correct branch name